# Don't display module name in which-function-mode

Tags: which-function-mode

When using `which-function-mode`, emacs displays not only the current function name but also the name of the module I am in. Is there a way to have `which-function-mode` display *only* the immediate function name, without the module name?

For example, instead of seeing this:

`MyApp::Controller::some_function`

I would like to only see:

`some_function`